# google maps info windows opening at extreme left instead of provided position

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am using google maps API to make some custom markers and i want to open a custom info window. I have been trying to set the position of the info window but its always opening on the extreme top left.

```
var markers = [
  [37.09024, -95.712891, "images/white-star.png"],
  [40.4173, -82.9071, "images/purple-star.png"],
  [31.9686, -99.9018, "images/yellow-star.png"],
];


for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
  var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][0], markers[i][1]);
  var icon = markers[i][2];
  marker[i] = infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: html,
    pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(200, 0)
  });
  marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: position,
    icon: icon,
    map: map,
  }).addListener('mouseover', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker[i]);
  });
}
```

Comment: With the posted code I get a javascript error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: html is not defined` Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem lies how to create marker and info window in your code.To create multiple markers in map, see code below .

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/otxeyhpo/)

```
function initMap() {
  var myLatLng = {
    lat: 40.4173,
    lng: -82.9071
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatLng
  });

  var markers = [
    [37.09024, -95.712891, "images/white-star.png"],
    [40.4173, -82.9071, "images/purple-star.png"],
    [31.9686, -99.9018, "images/yellow-star.png"],
  ];


  for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    (function(markers) {
      var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0], markers[1]);
      var icon = markers[2];
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: 'html',
        pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(200, 0)
      });

      var markerss = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map,
        //icon: icon,
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(markerss, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map, markerss);
      });
    })(markers[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`marker[i]` is not defined in this line:

```
infowindow.open(map, marker[i]);
```

Without a defined anchor, the infowindow ends up in the upper left hand corner of the map.

You can use `this` for the anchor in the `mouseover` event handler function:

```
infowindow.open(map, this);
```

You probably also want to remove the:

```
pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(200, 0)
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/qepLy0jj/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var markers = [
    [37.09024, -95.712891, "images/white-star.png"],
    [40.4173, -82.9071, "images/purple-star.png"],
    [31.9686, -99.9018, "images/yellow-star.png"],
  ];

  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var html = "marker";
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][0], markers[i][1]);
    var icon = markers[i][2];
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: html,
      // pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(200, 0)
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: position,
      // icon: icon,
      map: map,
    }).addListener('mouseover', function() {
      infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
    bounds.extend(position);
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```